# WlanConnect Connection attempt fail

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi, wlanapi

I am trying to connect to an unsecured network using the [WlanConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706613(v=vs.85).aspx) function. It is returning `ERROR_SUCCESS`, so far so good.

In my notification callback i receive `WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_CONNECTION_COMPLETE` followed instantly by `WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAIL`.

Can someone give me a hint how i can find out what causes the connection to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you just forgot to mention the part where you called `WlanRegisterNotification`, since you say that your notification callback is actually receiving notifications.

As it turns out, you're in luck—the API provides you with just such a hint. In the documentation for the structure passed to you in the callback function, [`WLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706278.aspx), it describes what the `WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAIL` notification code means:

> A connection attempt has failed.
>
> A connection consists of one or more connection attempts. An application may receive zero or more `wlan_notification_acm_connection_attempt_fail` notifications between receiving the `wlan_notification_acm_connection_start` notification and the `wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete` notification.
>
> The *pData* member points to a [`WLAN_CONNECTION_NOTIFICATION_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706848.aspx) structure that identifies the network information for the connection attempt that failed.

And that structure has a `wlanReasonCode` member that contains a [`WLAN_REASON_CODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707394.aspx) value that "indicates the reason for an operation failure." There are a bunch of error codes on that list. Check to see which one you are getting.

Also note that it is possible to receive a few `WLAN_NOTIFICATION_ACM_CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAIL` notifications before the connection ultimately connects successfully.